# Browsers and winsock on windows

Tags: windows, browser, winsock

Is thit true that all browsers on windows OS work thru winsock? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that all the browsers use actually Winsock2. It has several extensions over Winsock, most are related to the support of overlapped (asynchronous) I/O on sockets.

Specifically MS Internet Explorer uses a higher-level library called WinINet. Which in turn of course uses Winsock2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for a fact that they all do (what does "all" mean, anyway?) But what else would they use? Winsock is the Windows Sockets API, through which access to network cards is mediated.